Packer - Copy & Update file in one go
I am looking to make an Amazon AMI using Packer. I have a YAML file which I can copy across successfully.
"provisioners": [
 {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "flights.yaml",
    "destination": "/tmp/flights.yaml"
 }
]

However, there is one value in the file I would like to pass in as a variable.
 packer build \
    -var "ami_name=flights-november" \
    -var "source_ami=ami-XXX" \
    -var "seed_data={thisiswhatIwantinthefile}"
    ./ami.json

Is there a clean way to do this? Other than something like a search and replace?
connecting: false
 MCT: {thisiswhatIwanttoreplace}
 terminal-1:
   - jetblue
   - american
   - untied
 terminal-2:
   - airfrance
   - lufthansa


We need to see the relevant part of the flights.yaml file.

I have added the flights.yaml file

The first requirement is that you want a variable to use with the -var CLI argument. You need to declare this variable in your config:
variable "seed_data" {}

This enables:
packer build ... -var seed_data=<value> ...

Note that the above uses the HCL2 syntax. However, the template is named ami.json, and the content appears to be JSON. Note that this functionality you requested requires the supported HCL2 syntax (and is not possible otherwise), so please update the template usage if it in fact still using the old deprecated JSON syntax as indicated in the file extension and question content.
You can find more information about variable declarations in the documentation.
Next you want to render the variable value in the content of the flights.yaml file. For this you would most often invoke the templatefile function.
flights.pkrtpl.hcl:
connecting: false
  MCT: ${seed_data}
  terminal-1:
  - jetblue
  - american
  - untied
  terminal-2:
  - airfrance
  - lufthansa

Packer template:
provisioner "file" {
  destination = "/tmp/flights.yaml"
  content     = templatefile("${path.root}/flights.pkrtpl.hcl", { seed_data = var.seed_data })
}

